# Compiler AST how to implement statements and expressions

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

Currently working on a little toy compiler, consider this Code:

```
// AST base class
abstract class AST { /* codegen methods */}

// abstract classes for Statements and Expressions
abstract class Statement : AST {}
abstract class Expression : AST {}

// usage of the abstract classes
class CodeBlock : AST {
    public List<Statement> BlockStatements;
}
class BinOp : AST {
    public Expression LHS, RHS;
    public char Operator;
}

// a constant value is always an expression
class ConstantInt : Expression {
    public int Value;
}
```

Now to the problem how would I implement the `FunctionCall` class? If it is used in an expression it would be part of the expression like `min(4, 5) + 3` therefor `FunctionCall : Expression` makes sense. But then I can't have function calls in a block like this `{ writeToConsole("Hello World"); }` so the `FunctionCall : Statement` sounds reasonable but this would not work with expression syntax. Making `Statement` inherit from `Expression` would not work either since it would allow AST's like this `min(4, 5) + int a`.

I'd like to get suggestions on how to keep statements and expressions seperate except for things that can be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making it so that statements are expressions is indeed not a good idea (for the reason you point out). However making it so that expressions are statements has a lot more merit.

In fact most¹ languages' grammars have an entry similar to this:

```
statement ::= expression ';'
```

That is an expression followed by a semicolon is a statement, a so-called expression statement. In your AST you could represent this either by making `Expression` inherit `Statement` or by creating a class `ExpressionStatement`, which simply wraps `Expression`.

Besides allowing function calls as statements, it also allows other expressions as statements. For side-effecting expressions like assignments, composite assignments or increment expressions this makes a lot of sense.

For expressions without side effects, like simple arithmetic, it makes less sense. In C and C++ a statement like `a + b;` is in fact legal, but causes a warning in most compilers. In other languages there is an explicit rule that prohibits certain types of expressions to be used as statement expressions.

---

¹ Only taking into account those languages that have a distinction between statements and expressions at all, of course.

Comment: I like this approach, with the explicit `StatementExpression` rule can easily decide which expressions are valid statements.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of achieving this is working with interfaces. Use an IStatement interface and IExpression and make FunctionCall implement both. Besides, make your BinOp implement IExpression

Answer (score 0):

You should realize that you have "functions returning values" (which should be expressions), and "functions that do not return values (which should be statements).

So your problem goes away if you define ExpressionFunction and StatementFunction as separate classes.

An alternative: you can define Function as an expression, and define StatementFunction as an AST with a Function as an field.

Comment: Your first suggestion would make it impossible to use functions that do have a return value as statements. So if you were to call, say, the C `printf` function (which returns an int), you'd have to store the result in a variable (or do something else with it). The majority of programming languages do not require you to do that.

Comment: @sepp2k:  Yes, it would.  OP did not define his language, so he gets to make this choice.  Note I had a second suggestion, which I provided for exactly that reason.